# how to learn about ILGenerator programming?

Tags: .net, clr, il

I'm hunting for a short example on IL generation programming that includes:

- a return value
- branching on a null test
- assigning to a temporary variable, or having a method with a function return as an argument to another method

It'd be great if there was a resource with examples + line by line explanation of what is occuring.

Does VS 2010 help with tracing at the il level?

I could post some incomplete examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way to learn about IL is to write the code in e.g. C# and look at the generated IL. That way you can easily see what various code constructs map to. For a great book on the subject, I recommend [Expert .NET IL Assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463).

Comment: ty.  I'll look at that.  Seems less activity in the .net book world at the moment.  Hopefully that's not an indication of what's going on with the .net platform.

Comment: some decent documentation at MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.REFLECTION.EMIT.OPCODES.CALLVIRT);k(CALLVIRT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true

Comment: @sgtz: Sorry for not including that, I assumed you already about MSDN.

Comment: ... I went off using MSDN when the quality went down.  That's why I used the word 'decent'.  I was surprised.  MS lifted their game when I wasn't looking.

Comment: ty for pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to get a good result just through experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

One good way is to write C# code that does what you want, and then debug it at the IL level using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). You could just look at the generated IL, but if you have a hard time figuring out what's going on, it's enlightening being able to step through it.

Comment: is IL Spy a stand alone tool, or does it also work as a plugin?  Just playing with it now.

Comment: It's a standalone tool, it's not possible to run it within Visual Studio if that's what you were thinking of.